# Specifying order when using reduce to concatenate members of RDD[String]

Tags: apache-spark

I was trying out `reduce()` functionality so I tried the following:

```
scala> val stringSeq = Seq("The","quick", "brown", "fox") 
stringSeq: Seq[String] = List(The, quick, brown, fox)
```

Create an RDD from it:

```
scala> val stringSeqRDD=sc.parallelize(stringSeq)
stringSeqRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:29
```

Concatenate the elements:

```
scala> stringSeqRDD.reduce((x,y) => (x + " " + y))
res3: String = quick The brown fox
```

My question is how can I impose an ordering on the strings that I am concatenating? Do I have to convert to a PairRDD first and impose an ordering based on the keys so as to produce "The quick brown fox" as the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain order by using `foldLeft()` or `foldRight()`.
In your case `foldLeft()` will work.

```
stringseq.foldLeft("")((x,y)=>(x+" "+y))
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess if I wanted to get this from the RDD I would do

    `stringSeqRDD.collect.foldLeft("")((x,y)=>(x+" "+y))`

Comment: Yes you can use it stringSeqRDD.collect.foldLeft("")((x,y)=>(x+" "+y))